# ERC20 token balance = 0 in MetaMask

Tags: erc-20, metamask, chainlink

While setting up a test ChainLink node on Rinkeby, I sent some test LINK to my address. The ChainLink web interface showed a balance of 0 LINK. So I checked EtherScan. The transaction succeeded and the LINK was in the account. But it was not showing up in the ChainLink node. My node gets its data from Infura, so it should be perfectly synced I would assume.

I sent some test ETH to the same account and it showed up immediately in the ChainLink node. But the LINK never showed up. I sent the ETH after I sent the LINK, so I would think that means the problem is not related to syncing.

I decided to try a test with MetaMask on Rinkeby. Created an account, sent some test ETH and LINK to it. The ETH was there almost immediately. The LINK never showed up.

EtherScan link to the account I tried in ChainLink:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xfbcf84beb73b769627ed9cf110e1e6352243d9e4#tokentxns

EtherScan link to the account I tried in MetaMask:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7e4066dc94354768915b25eff30944ccb4bea28c#tokentxns

I've tried restarting the browser.
I've tried switching to a different browser.
I've tried changing networks and changing back again.

People have been having this problem with various ERC-20 tokens for years. No solution I have found works.

Comment: Hi there. They won't show up in Metamask without adding the Rinkeby Chainlink contract address (scroll to the bottom of the Assets tab and click Add Token).

Comment: I did that. My Assets tab shows "0 LINK". The Activity tab shows only the ETH transaction, but no LINK transactions.

Comment: Hmm. The LINK shows up in Etherscan - what address are you using for the Chainlink contract?

Comment: I'm not seeing the address of the contract. When I click Add Token, I can select from a list of token names, but I don't see any way to choose (or even view) the contract address. But the token name shows up in my Assets list with a balance of 0.

Comment: Ah, okay. You'll need to use the Custom Token tab, then manually add the address and symbol. (Address is 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709) I don't think Metamask is intelligent enough to give you the Rinkeby config - I suspect it's added the mainnet LINK address.

Comment: Perfect :-) Agree that it's a shame it doesn't work a little more seamlessly!